# Yii2 DataPorivider $totalSum for a column

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have Order and OrderSearch models.

In order list (actionIndex) with GridView there is a filtering and sorting.
On of the columns in Order is order_total (sum of all the products in order).

I need to implement SUM of all order_total in GridView.
If I do it manually by counting ActiveDataProvider->getModels() with array_map I spend 3 seconds for 3000 orders (localhost). I don't want to miss so much time.

I see two ways to make it faster:

1. Create cache for every filter and update it by lifetime (horrible)
2. The most interesting that I can do it right in OrderSearch->search() method as $query method. But I don't understand how can I pass it in a controller.

Example of a code for 2nd way:

```
class OrderSearch extends Order
{

    public $totalSum; 

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Order::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        $this->totalSum = $query->sum('order_total'); // this works very fast

        return $dataProvider;
    }

}
```

After that I'm trying to get this property in Controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new OrderSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 100;

    // code below works too slow and depends on pagination page size
    // $orders = $dataProvider->getModels();
    // $totalSum = 1.0;
    // array_map(function($item) use (&$totalSum) {
    //     $totalSum += (float)$item->attributes['order_total'];
    // }, $dataProvider->getModels());

    // here I get an error
    // Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
    // Getting unknown property: yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::totalSum
    $totalSum = $dataProvider->totalSum;

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'totalSum' => $totalSum,
    ]);
}
```

How can I set custom property for DataProvider?

Comment: Use `$totalSum = $searchModel['totalSum'];` in your controller rather than `$totalSum = $dataProvider->totalSum;`

Comment: Thank you! It was easier than I supposed :))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

So, `$dataProvider` will be the return of that method. And, as you can see here:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    // code

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

The method `search` is returning an [ActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html). You should, after using that method, call the attribute of the original class:

```
$searchModel = new OrderSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams); // run search, so now we have a totalSum.
$totalSum = $searchModel->totalSum;
```

Answer (score 0):

get the `$totalSum` and add a field.

change

```
$query = Order::find();
```

to

```
$query = Order::find()->select(['*', 'totalSum' => new yii\db\Expression($totalSum)]);
```

watch escaping if you are using strings!

you could also consider using subqueries, like http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

e.g.

```
$subQuery = Order::find()->sum('order_total');
$query = Order::find()->select(['*', 'totalSum' => $subQuery]);
```